# Rendering streamfield block a certain way if booleanBlock is True

Tags: python, django, jinja2, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Hello I'm currently new to django/wagtail. I'm working on an about page that shows previous and current work/positions. I've made the positions streamfield blocks since the amount of experience isn't limited. Here is the code to my models.

```
#Create experience block 
class ExperienceBlockStruct(StructBlock):
    position_title = CharBlock(help_text="Enter a previous position title.")
    description = CharBlock(help_text="Job description")
    current_position = BooleanBlock(required=False, help_text="Check if 
    current position")

class Meta:
    template = 'blocks/experience_block.html'


class ExperienceBlock(StreamBlock):
    experience = ExperienceBlockStruct(icon="form")
```

And here is the page where I use the models

```
class About(Page):
    profile_pic = "some image reduced code bc it currently works"
    bio = RichTextField(blank=True)
    resume = "some document reduced code bc it currently works"
    experience = StreamField(ExperienceBlock())
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('profile_pic'),
        FieldPanel('bio'),
        DocumentChooserPanel('resume'),
        StreamFieldPanel('experience'),
    ]
```

Now the issue I'm having is how to render the blocks where the `current_position = True` in a different area than those that are not.
I've tried

```
templates/about.html
{% for block in page.experience %}
  {% if block.current_position %}
    {% include_block block %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that doesnt render anything. I've also tried to

```
<div class="experience">
  {% if value.current_position %}
    {{ value.position_title }}
  {% else %}
    {{ value.position_title }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

but that creates a new div for every block. What I would like to achieve is something like in `blocks/experience_block.html`

```
<div>
  Current position(s): {% blocks with current_postion == True %}
</div>   

<div>
  Past position(s): {% blocks with current_postion == False %}
</div>
```

How could I go about achieving something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first template snippet was almost correct - you just need to check `block.value.current_position` rather than `block.current_position`:

```
{% for block in page.experience %}
    {% if block.value.current_position %}
        {% include_block block %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is because looping over `page.experience` gives you a series of `BoundBlock` objects that tell you the `block_type` (always `'experience'` in your case) alongside the block value. See [BoundBlocks and values](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/topics/streamfield.html#boundblocks-and-values) for a more detailed explanation.

You can do the same thing in your experience_block.html template (using `{% for block in value %}` rather than `{% for block in page.experience %}`) - although note that the `Meta` template definition needs to go on `ExperienceBlock` rather than `ExperienceBlockStruct`, because that's the one that has access to the full list to loop over, rather than a single record.

To make things neater, I'd suggest defining a `get_context` method on the block, so that you're doing the data manipulation within Python code rather than inside the template...

```
class ExperienceBlock(StreamBlock):
    experience = ExperienceBlockStruct(icon="form")

    def get_context(self, value, parent_context=None):
        context = super(ExperienceBlock, self).get_context(value, parent_context=parent_context)
        context['current_positions'] = [block for block in value if block.value.current_position]
        context['past_positions'] = [block for block in value if not block.value.current_position]
        return context

    class Meta:
        template = 'blocks/experience_block.html'
```

This will make the variables `current_positions` and `past_positions` available on the template.